# How to encapsulate this variable into the string?

Tags: php

I want to encapsulate this variable into the string, but I always get an error:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
   echo "<tr>"
   for($j = 0; $j < $_POST['columns'] $j++) {
      echo "<td>$_POST['row{$i}column{$j}']</td>"; // << I get an error. Please help me encapsulate this.. I'm so confused.
   }
}
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: You mean concatenate not encapsulate : )

Answer (score 5):

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
   echo '<tr>';
   for($j = 0; $j < $_POST['columns'] $j++) {
      echo '<td>' . $_POST['row' . $i . 'column' . $j] . '</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
   echo "<tr>"
   for($j = 0; $j < $_POST['columns'] $j++) {
      echo '<td>'.$_POST['row'.$i.'column'.$j].'</td>';
   }
}
```

Just concatenate the String with the . operator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing ";" after `echo "<tr>"`
second you are missing ";" after `$_POST['columns']`

and this is your solution

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
   echo "<tr>";
   for($j = 0; $j < $_POST['columns']; $j++) {
      echo "<td>{$_POST['row{$i}column{$j}']}</td>"; // << I get an error. Please help me encapsulate this.. I'm so confused.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered, but I would like to point out a little known fact about [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

```
echo '<td>' . $_POST['row'.$i.'column'.$j] . '</td>';
```

In this code, two concatenations are taking place,

'row' . $i . 'column' . $j, and

'< td >' . $_POST[...] . '< / td >'

A concatenation requires a temporary variable to be created on the stack, value transferred into the variable, and then the temp var passed into, in this case, either the array ref or the echo construct.

To save time and memory, try this instead:

```
echo '<td>', $_POST['row'.$i.'column'.$j], '</td>';
```

echo can take multiple arguments separated by columns. This saves both the time and memory consumed by a concatenation. Not much saved in the short run, but over time the improvement will add up.  And it reduces confusion down the road over what is being concatenated, and what is being passed to output.

Comment: This should be a comment - but to clarify, commas are only faster if there is a variable in the mix. `echo 'aaaa'.'aaaa'.'aaa';` is more than twice as fast as `echo 'aaaa','aaaa','aaa';`